# Timer does not stop with my if statement, did I place in in the wrong part?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 if ($('<input/>').length == 0) {
      T.stop();
  }
```

the above is how I create the timer stop function.

This is where the part of the code has been placed:

```
 $.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) { 
            if (!syllable || !syllable.trim().length) {
           // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
               return;
            }
 var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
                class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
            });

            var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
                'type': 'text',
                'class': 'form-control syl-input',
                'name':  +c++,
                'id': +idsyll++
            }).on('blur', function() {
                var cValue = $(this).val();

                if(cValue === "") {
                   return;
                }

            if (cValue === syllable) {
                correctSylls.push(cValue);
                console.log(correctSylls);
            }

            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
                $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').each(function () { 
                $(this).replaceWith(getCorrectBtn($(this).val()))
            });

            S.addRight();
            S.playRight();

         } else if (cValue !== syllable){
          // $(this).css({'color':'#e00413'});
              S.playWrong();
              S.addWrong();
            }
        });

            innerSylCol.append(sylInput);
            sylRow.append(innerSylCol);
        });
        idsyll = 0;

        sylCol.append(sylRow);

        exer.append(colLeft, sylCol);

        exerciseArea.append(exer);
    });
    return exerciseArea;

         if ($('<input/>').length == 0) {
              T.stop();
          }
}
```

The loop creates inputs based on words in my array, the inputs change to buttons when the inserted data is correct. I am trying to create it such that when the length of the inputs becomes 0 (so there are no input fields left, only buttons) it will stop the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. This code:

   ```
   if ($('<input/>').length == 0) {
   ```

   **creates** an `input` element, which is put in a jQuery wrapper, and then checks the number of elements in the wrapper. So the condition will always be false, because the `length` will always be 1. To **search for** `input` elements, remove the `<` and `/>`:  `$("input")`
2. You need to run that code in response to some condition (perhaps within the timer itself?) that might make `$("input").length` `0` by removing all `input` elements. Your quoted code is incomplete, but it doesn't *seem* like that check is being done later or in response to some event where `input`s may have been removed.